# Adding wildcards (the `%`s) to the actual query itself rather than in the parameter

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible in the following query statement to add the wildcards to the actual query itself rather than how I am doing it in the parameters?

Here is what I have:

```
query = params[:query].present? ? params[:query] : params[:'search-keywords']
approved_user_ids  = logged_in_user.approved_users.pluck(:id) << logged_in_user.id
search_results = User.where(['name LIKE :query OR operator_id LIKE :query', { query:
                             "%#{query}%" }]).where.not(id: approved_user_ids).order(:name)
```

Where I have the `{query: "%#{query}#"}` can I take that out and put it up where I am using the `:query OR operator_id LIKE :query'?`

Comment: You could apply a function to modify the value. `... LIKE concat('%',concat(:query, '%'))` What is the reasoning for this?

Comment: The reasoning for this is that it will be more readable. Is there a way to do this without concat? @JRD

Comment: Not without creating your own custom query parser. Not sure how the wildcard characters(%) make it less readable, but if you don't like the way it looks, you could play around with different ways of concatenating strings.